# tornado, make on_finish() asynchronous

Tags: asynchronous, tornado, coroutine

override method on_finish().
Decorate this method with `.gen.coroutine` to make it asynchronous, it worked.

```
@gen.coroutine
def on_finish(self):
    print("==========on_finish==============")
```

but use `async def` to make it asynchronous, it failed.

```
async def on_finish(self):
    print("==========on_finish==============")

# RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'BaseHandler.on_finish' was never awaited
```

self.on_finish()

Why can't I use `async def` to make it asynchronous？

Comment: I suppose it's because [tornado runs on_finish() synchronously](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/master/tornado/web.py#L1044). Your first example is not _worked_, it just hasn't raised any error because it's syntactically correct and failed silently. I see possible workaround in a `add_callback()` call.

Comment: Yes, Fian is right. Tornado doesn't support making `on_finish` an async function. But what are you trying to do? Why do you want to make it asynchronous?

Comment: I use TorMySQL to asynchronous connect mysql. In prepare() function, I get a db.conn(), I want to close the connection automatically in on_finish() function. The function db.conn.close() must be asynchronous

Comment: @Lvxiuquan Like Fian has already pointed out above, you can schedule to close the connection by using `add_callback()` method. Tornado will run it asynchronously. I can post sample code if you want.

Comment: @xyres Don't bother. I get it, thx.

Answer (score 6):

Coroutines have a different interface than regular functions. When overriding a method, you should make it a coroutine (or not) according to its documentation. All overridable methods in Tornado that may be coroutines say so in their documentation, and `on_finish` is not one of them.

What happens if you use a coroutine when the superclass doesn't expect it? As you see, this depends on the kind of coroutine. `@gen.coroutine` is "self-starting", so the coroutine will start, but nothing will wait for it to finish, and if it raises an exception, there is nowhere for that exception to be caught (so it will just be logged by the IOLoop). `async def` coroutines do not start automatically, something *must* `await` them, so if you use one where the caller is not expecting a coroutine, nothing will happen.

If you need to use a coroutine from a method where this is not allowed, you need to decide who's going to wait on the coroutine and handle its exceptions. If you don't need to catch exceptions and can just leave them for the logs, you can use `IOLoop.add_callback` to explicitly give this responsibility to the IOLoop:

```
def on_finish(self):
    IOLoop.current().add_callback(self.on_finish_async)

async def on_finish_async(self):
    ...
```